# Is there any method that I can use to properly implement the delete and edit logic in this code and alternative for select to choose multiple roles?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, axios

- I could not delete and edit properly this code. I always got an error when I want to delete and edit the newest user I created.
- I couldn't set multiple roles, I have tried React Select but i could not configure it properly. I have tried so many methods but it did not work out properly. I think it has something to do with axios or the id in the elements.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { FiArrowLeft } from "react-icons/fi";
import { BsFillPersonPlusFill, BsThreeDotsVertical } from "react-icons/bs";
import { MdOutlineEmail } from "react-icons/md";
//import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
//import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
//import {
  register,
  reset,
} from "../../features/authentication/authenticationSlice";
import "./Admin.css";
import axios from "axios";
import FormInputs from "./FormInputs";
import AdminSidebar from "./AdminSideBar";

const Admin = () => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [showEditModal, setShowEditModal] = useState(false);
  const [showDeleteModal, setShowDeleteModal] = useState(false);
  const [adminItems, setAdminItems] = useState([]);
  const [roles, setRoles] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [pic, setPic] = useState(null);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [password2, setPassword2] = useState("");
  const [editIndex, setEditIndex] = useState(null); // Added new state for tracking the index of the item being edited
  const [showModal2, setShowModal2] = useState(
    Array(adminItems.length).fill(false)
  );
  const [deleteIndex, setDeleteIndex] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setShowModal2(Array(adminItems.length).fill(false));
  }, [adminItems]);

  const toggleModal2 = (index) => {
    setShowModal2((prevShowModal2) => {
      const newShowModal2 = [...prevShowModal2];
      newShowModal2[index] = !newShowModal2[index];
      return newShowModal2;
    });
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    if (name === "roles") {
      const selectedOptions = Array.from(
        e.target.selectedOptions,
        (option) => option.value
      );
      setRoles(selectedOptions); // Store the array of selected roles directly
    } else if (name === "name") {
      setName(value);
    } else if (name === "email") {
      setEmail(value);
    } else if (name === "password") {
      setPassword(value);
    } else if (name === "password2") {
      setPassword2(value);
    }
  };

  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    setPic(file);
  };

  const handlePasswordConfirm = () => {
    if (password !== password2) {
      alert("Passwords do not match");
    }
  };

  const handleAddItem = () => {
    if (!roles || !name || !email || !password || !password2) {
      alert("Please fill in all the required fields");
      return;
    }

    const newUser = {
      roles,
      name,
      email,
      pic,
      password,
    };

    axios
      .post("/api/admins", newUser)
      .then((response) => {
        setAdminItems((prevItems) => [...prevItems, response.data]);
        setRoles("");
        setName("");
        setEmail("");
        setPic(null);
        setPassword("");
        setPassword2("");
        setShowModal(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error adding user:", error);
      });
  };

  const handleEditItem = () => {
    if (editIndex === null) {
      alert("User not found");
      return;
    }

    const admin = adminItems[editIndex]; // Retrieve the admin being edited
    const adminId = admin.id; // Get the ID from the admin object

    const updatedUser = {
      roles: roles, // Update the roles assignment to use the roles state directly
      name,
      email,
      pic,
      password,
    };

    axios
      .put(`/api/admins/${adminId}`, updatedUser)
      .then((response) => {
        const updatedItems = [...adminItems];
        updatedItems[editIndex] = response.data;
        setAdminItems(updatedItems);
        setShowEditModal(false);
        setEditIndex(null);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert("Error editing user:", error);
      });
  };

  const handleDeleteItem = (id) => {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?")) {
      axios
        .delete(`/api/admins/${id}`)
        .then((res) => {
          setMessage(res.data.message);
          setShowDeleteModal(true);

          // Update the adminItems state after successful deletion
          setAdminItems((prevItems) =>
            prevItems.filter((item) => item.id !== id)
          );
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          alert("Error deleting user:", error);
        });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("/api/admins")
      .then((response) => {
        const admins = response.data.map((admin) => ({
          ...admin,
          id: admin._id, // Add the id field to each admin object
        }));
        setAdminItems(admins);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error fetching admin items:", error);
      });
  }, []);

  const handleEditClick = (index) => {
    const admin = adminItems[index];
    setRoles(admin.roles);
    setName(admin.name);
    setEmail(admin.email);
    setPassword(""); // Clear the password field when opening the edit modal
    setPassword2(""); // Clear the password2 field when opening the edit modal
    setEditIndex(index); // Set the editIndex state with the correct index
    setShowEditModal(true);
  };
  const handleAddClick = () => {
    setRoles("");
    setName("");
    setEmail("");
    setPassword(""); // Clear the password field when opening the edit modal
    setPassword2(""); // Clear the password2 field when opening the edit modal

    setShowModal(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <AdminSidebar />
      <div className="all">
        <div className="container-admin">
          <section className="section-admin">
            <div className="side-line" />
            <div className="side-lines" />
            <div className="admin-controller">ADMIN CONTROLLER</div>
          </section>
          <section className="section-back">
            <FiArrowLeft />
            <div className="back">BACK</div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <div className="main-section">
          <section className="sub-section-1">
            <div className="user-container">
              <div className="User">User</div>
              <div className="admin-per-department">Admin per department</div>
            </div>
            <div className="class-buttons">
              <button
                className="add-user-button-container"
                onClick={handleAddClick}>
                <BsFillPersonPlusFill />
                <div className="new-role">New Role</div>
              </button>
            </div>
          </section>
          {showModal && (
            <div className="modal-overlay">
              <div className="modal-content">
                <h3>Add New User</h3>
                <div>
                  <div className="permission">
                    by adding a new user you are giving them permission to make
                    changes in this department.
                  </div>
                </div>

                <FormInputs
                  roles={roles}
                  name={name}
                  email={email}
                  password={password}
                  password2={password2}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  handleFileChange={handleFileChange}
                  handlePasswordConfirm={handlePasswordConfirm}
                />

                <button onClick={handleAddItem}>Add</button>
                <button onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}>Cancel</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}

          <section className="sub-section-2">
            {adminItems.map((item, index) => (
              <div className="user-sub-section" key={index}>
                <div className="triple-dot">
                  <div className="dot">
                    <BsThreeDotsVertical
                      onClick={() => {
                        toggleModal2(index); // Toggle showModal2 for the clicked user item
                      }}
                    />
                    {showModal2[index] && (
                      <div className="dot-menu">
                        <button
                          onClick={() => {
                            handleEditClick(index); // Pass the index to handle the edit click
                            toggleModal2(index);
                          }}>
                          Edit
                        </button>
                        <button
                          onClick={() => {
                            handleDeleteItem(item.id); // Pass the item's id instead of index
                            toggleModal2(index);
                          }}>
                          Delete
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="profile-container">
                  <img
                    alt="User Profile"
                    className="User-Profile"
                    src={
                      item.pic && item.pic.data
                        ? URL.createObjectURL(
                            new Blob([item.pic.data], {
                              type: item.pic.contentType,
                            })
                          )
                        : "https://icon-library.com/images/anonymous-avatar-icon/anonymous-avatar-icon-25.jpg"
                    }
                  />
                  <div className="active-status" />
                </div>
                <div className="employee-name">{item.name}</div>
                <div className="admin-container">
                  <div className="admin-at">Admin at</div>
                  <div className="department-name">
                    {item.roles || "No Role"}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="email-section">
                  <div className="email-container">
                    <MdOutlineEmail />
                  </div>
                  <div className="employee-email">{item.email}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </section>
          {/* Edit Modal */}
          {showEditModal && (
            <div className="modal-overlay">
              <div className="modal-content">
                {/* Modal content for editing user */}
                <h3>Edit User</h3>

                <FormInputs
                  roles={roles}
                  name={name}
                  email={email}
                  password={password}
                  password2={password2}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  handleFileChange={handleFileChange}
                  handlePasswordConfirm={handlePasswordConfirm}
                />
                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    handleEditItem();
                  }}>
                  Save
                </button>
                <button onClick={() => setShowEditModal(false)}>Cancel</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Admin;
```

Comment: what error are you getting and what part of this code is throwing the error?

Comment: When I edit the recently added user in the HandleEdit and HandleDelete functions, I encounter errors. However, when I edit the previously created user, it is editable. The same case applies to the delete operation.

Comment: what are the errors? one could make guesses at the issue but lead you down the wrong path. specific errors are very useful in debugging. There are various point where this could be happening - which is why specific errors are useful  And, are you actually hitting that error block - or are the errors coming from subsequent logic because there is no user at that point?